# Saving HTML5 Canvas to PNG in Chrome 19

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement the ability to save the contents of an HTML5 canvas as a PNG and it is failing on Chrome 19. I am using a solution similar to this one:
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

If you test on Chrome 19 it gives the following error:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/octet-stream: "data:image/octet-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Chrome 19 does not allow "Save As" for images served via DATA URIs. Tested on Canary and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case nobody else answers, send the octet stream to server-side PHP processing and append an invisible `<iframe>` with these headers

```
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image".time().".png");
 header("Content-Type: image/png");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: I was trying to solve it on the client side. It worked on the old Chrome, but seems to have been broken now.

Answer (score 0):

It just won't work client-side on Chrome 19, I've tried everything. I put together a simple server-side solution in PHP and you can see how it's done: https://github.com/coolbloke1324/FontSheetGenerator/blob/master/saver/savePng.php

The file expects to be POSTed the data from a form and that there will be two variables:

**imageFileName** - The name of the file including the extension e.g. "hello.png". The filename is converted to lower case and all spaces are converted to underscores - easy to change this behaviour in the script should you wish.

**formImageData** - The result of calling canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

So your HTML form might look something like this:

```
<form action="saver/savePng.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="formImageFileName" name="imageFileName">
    <input type="hidden" id="formImageData" name="imageData" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveImageButton" value="Save Image..." />
</form>
```

You would want to update the value of the element "formImageData" to the data from the toDataUrl() call before submitting the form.